# Unit Testing of RecyclerView items with counts

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

Here I'm trying to write some basic unit test cases and I have written 2 test cases as

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> main = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);


@Test
public void testShouldLaunchTheMainActivityAndFindItemsInTheList() throws Exception {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) main.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    assertThat(recyclerView.getScrollBarSize(), is(11));
}

@Before
public void init() {
    main.getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
}

@Test
public void testShouldTestTheItemNameInTheList() throws Exception {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) main.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    if (recyclerView.getScrollBarSize() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getScrollBarSize(); i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition
                        (1, typeTextIntoFocusedView("Flag")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes both the test cases get passed successfully but sometimes second case gets failed and when I test on another device first one also gets failed. Anyone can help me out of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `recyclerView.getScrollBarSize()`, you should change it to `recyclerView.getChildCount()`. This returns the count of the views inside the RecyclerView.